# VBA webpage dropdown by name

Tags: vba

Hi I have the following webpage dropdown I want to select a value from:

```
<select name="ad_award_name" onchange="javascript:submitLink(document.Form0,'NotRequired');" displayname="Award Name">
```

I am trying to use the below code but it throws in the error message on `If drp.Options(x).Text = "TEST1" Then` of "Run time error '438', Object does not support this property or method".

```
Set drp = ie.document.getElementsByName("ad_award_name")

    For x = 0 To drp.Options.Length - 1
        If drp.Options(x).Text = "TEST1" Then
            drp.selectedIndex = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: Is the web page accessible to us?

Comment: drp will be an array "get elements", so use drp(0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drp` will be an array "get elements", so use `drp(0).`

Comment: Perfect Nathan! So simple and I wasted so much time trying to find a solution. How did you know that GetelementsByName produces and Array and GetelementbyID does not? Is the clue in the singular? i.e. no 's' on element?